# How do you transform this code into pure functional javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, functional-programming

```
var files = [];
for (const entry of Object.entries(collection)) {
    var folder = "";
    entry.forEach(item => {
        if (typeof item == "string") {
            folder = item;
        }

        if (typeof item == "object") {
            item.forEach(file => {
                files.push(folder + "/" + file); // append files only (recursive)      
            })
        }
        
    });
    // sometimes lists contain names of children directories. check with the top parent to exclude directory names
    files = files.filter(x => !Object.keys(collection).includes(x));
}
console.log(files);
```

There is a javascript object `collection` which is a collection of key-value pairs representing some directory.
Each key is the name of a subdirectory and its value is of type list, particularly a list of filenames only that are inside that directory.

This code works and it gets a list of absolute filepath names from the base directory recursively through some additional logic and concatenation.

I'm having a hard time rewriting this code to purely use .map(), .filter(), .find(), .pipe() or curry methods

Feedback appreciated

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [codereview.se]. However be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my answer

```
var files = Object.entries(collection)
            .map(entries => entries
            .filter(entry => typeof entry == "object")
            .map(files => files
            .map(file => entries[0] + "/" + file))) // first entry will be the folder name to concatenate
            .flat().flat()
            .filter(x => !Object.keys(collection).includes(x));
```

Return list and count is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you enough to get started,
I'd also suggest to edit the Q and add an example of `input` and `output` for this function...

```js
const join = ([folder, files]) => files.reduce(
  (res, file) => ({...res, [`${folder}/${file}`]: 1 }),
  {},
);

const fn = ([head, ...tail]) => Object
  .assign(join(head), tail.length ? fn(tail) : {});
  
const toUniquePaths = (data) => Object.keys(
  fn(Object.entries(data)),
);

// ====

const data = {
  a: ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
  b: ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'],
  c: ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'],
  d: ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5'],
  e: ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', /* dupes */ 'e5', 'e4'],
};

console.log(
  toUniquePaths(data),
);
```